# How to check the relation value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

Write in ruby on rails and use neo4j database.

Post and User are two classes. Flag is a relationship from User to Post.

Default value of flag is false. If someone put a flag on a post. The flag value will become true.

Flag class:

```
class Flag
 include Neo4j::ActiveRel
 include Neo4j::Timestamps

 from_class :User
 to_class :Post
 type :FLAG_POST

 property :flag, type: Boolean

 validates_presence_of :flag
end
```

Flag action in post controller:

```
def flag
  flag = Flag.new(from_node: current_user, to_node: @post, flag: true)

  respond_to do |format|
   if flag.save
     format.js { render :index }
   else
     format.js { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Error putting flag on post.'}
   end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= button_to "flag", flag_post_path(post), class: 'btn btn-default', method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to flag this post?' }, remote: true %>
```

Also, I want to add a alert when put the flag. If the post have been put a flag, the web will alert the user "The post has been put a flag". How can I check whether the flag value is true or false? I checked the neo4j graph, and the relationship has been built. But I don't know whether the flag value is changed or not.

I just start learning rails and neo4j. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flag.valid?` to check if the object is valid for saving.

Comment: In controller? or in the view file? What's the type of  'flag.valid?'  I just try 'post.flag.valid?'. It shows wrong..

Comment: sorry, in the controller you have the flag variable, if you call flag.valid? it will return  true or false.

Comment: Does it do the same thing as `flag.save`?

Comment: no, #valid? only checks if the object is valid for saving but does nothing more. #save method also saves the object if able.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do the alert if the flag has been put?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the value on click using jquery and pass the changed value. Or you can simply change the value from whatever it is every time. Something like:

```
$('.js-flag').on('click', function(e){ 
  // you'll need to add that js-flag class to your flag
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/posts/flag', // create this route if doesn't exist
     data: {
       // whatever data you want to pass
       // need to pass the post_id at a minimum
     }
  }).done(function(ajax_response){
     console.log('success!');
  })
})
```

Make sure you have a route in place for flag in your routes.rb file.

Inside your controller change the value of the flag.

Comment: Sorry, it's a little difficult for me to understand your code... could you explain it more? thx

Comment: It's jquery. Basically the code listens for when someone clicks an element with the js-flag class. When that happens, it triggers a request to a controller action and then runs the code inside that action. In the `.done` portion you can call your `alert('Flagged!')` function.